# create and remove subdirectory for generated files in Makefile.am

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, automake

I am using autotools for my project.

While building Qt there are the generated `moc_*.cpp` and `ui_*.h` files which I want to have them in a gen subdirectory. The directory and the generated files should be created by make and removed my make clean.

Have anyone here done this before? I'll appreciate it really much!

Answer (score 0):

```
targetdir/bin/launcher: sourcefile1 sourcefile1 sourcefile1 | dep1
     mkdir -pv "${@D}"
     # the rest
```

cleaning very much depends on your makefile structure. Please post a sample if you need help

Comment: I missed the automake tag there... hope it helped anyway

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about removing the directory off the top of my head, but you can list any generated files in `CLEANFILES` in your `Makefile.am`.